# Unable to find package NETStandard.Library

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package, .net-standard

I tried to add a new Class library(.Net Standard) in Visual studio 2019. But I get [this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1WeG.png):

> Unable to find package NETStandard.Library. No packages exist with
> this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages.

I haven't added any code to this file yet. When I go to NugetManager I can see [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKMCr.png):

> NetStandard.Library not available at this source

Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Comment: Can you display packages sources? In Visual Studio, you can Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> Packages Sources

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your package source in visual studio is on the Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages. You should Go to Package Manager Settings (Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Package Manager Settings).
On the package sources section enter 
Name : nuget.org 
source :https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

 add this package source to your visual studio and click ok.

Comment: It worked.I cannot thank you enough. I was struggling with this issue for more than two days. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: What if I want to develop on an offline pc? How can I get the NETStandard.library packages in a local folder?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this with a 3.1 exe referencing a .net standard 2.1 assemly.

```
NU1102: Unable to find package NETStandard.Library with version (>= 1.6.0)
  - Found 10 version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version: 1.6.0 ]
  - Found 0 version(s) in Local Cloud Packages (For VSTS builds)
```

I addressed this by making the referenced assembly's `<TargetFramework>` in csproj match the exe project's `<TargetFramework>`.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this particular issue. My problem was not resolved by the other answers here.

There was a `packages-lock.json` file in my project. All I had to do was delete it.