# .NET MAUI: A Bunch of Errors Being Thrown from the Default Template After A Fresh Installation

Tags: c#, maui

I have used Visual Studio Community 2022 to install .NET MAUI from the Visual Studio Installer. I was following instructions for getting [started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/first-app?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=vswin&pivots=devices-windows), but there were build errors. I did noticed that even without compiling the first build, several errors are shown. Here's the [list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqLBu.jpg).

No changes were made from the given default template. I've reinstalled .NET MAUI from Visual Studio Installer again, and nothing has changed. I've also installed .NET 6 and 7 runtime to no avail. Switching to .NET 6.0 to 7.0 on a new solution also did nothing.

What happened?

Edit - By Jason's request, here are some errors that seems noteworthy:

- NU1603 MauiApp4 depends on Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools (>= 10.0.22000.194) but Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools 10.0.22000.194 was not found. An approximate best match of Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools 10.0.22621.1 was resolved.
- NU1101    Unable to find package Microsoft.Maui.Core.Ref.ios. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages
- NU1101    Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Runtime.linux-x64. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages
- NU1101    Unable to find package Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Runtime.maccatalyst-x64. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages
- NU1101    Unable to find package Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Runtime.win-x64. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-packs, Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages

Comment: Please do not post errors as images.  Copy the text of a sampling of errors and post them

Comment: I would delete Visual Studio, start over.

Comment: Check the first edit, @Jason , would this be sufficient?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, I've uninstalled Visual Studio completely through the Visual Studio Installer. Same story with 189 errors. Looking at the sample error listings, it seems like something has forgotten to download. I've seen other posts about putting NuGet, so could that be one way to go?

Comment: It sounds like it is looking for nuget packages in the local cache instead of online.  Try clearing your nuget cache and then manually restoring nuget pkgs in the solution

Comment: *"with 189 errors."* After attempting to build? Intellisense errors BEFORE doing the FIRST build are not meaningful. And be sure to create a NEW project, in a new folder. The old one has bad information in its `.vs` hidden folder and/or its `.bin` and `.obj` folders.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Yes. Even after that. I've created a new project and that number of errors still persist, even after building.

Comment: @Jason, How would I do that? I have never worked with NuGet before, but I did noticed under the manage NuGet tab says that those installed are implicitly referenced by an SDK. They are Microsoft.Maui.Dependencies, Microsoft.Maui.Extensions, Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools, and System.Runtime.InteropServices.NFloat.Internal.  There were also these warnings in the Error List that mentions the need of Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools 10.0.22000.194, but instead uses the 10.0.22621.1 version to automatically resolve the issue. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

These 189 errors are being thrown since, as Jason once mentioned, is due to the solution looking for the local files instead of online. I've found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63633575/12751302) from another Stack Overflow post that fixed the issue. It's unclear as to why it has not been initially included.